# How to use mutate_at over multiple columns specified as function argument

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to overwrite multiple columns specified in the function argument based on condition in case_when. However, columns are not being updated. Any advice on what is not working in this code?

```
library(dplyr)
# create dataset
data <- data.frame(a = rbinom(10, 1, .5), b = rnorm(10, 5, 1), c = rnorm(10, 3, 1), d = rnorm(10, 5, 3))
# create ordered factor with column names (needed because of other pieces in my code)
column_names <- factor(names(data), levels = names(data), ordered = T)
# subset relevant columns (will be done many times)
cols1 <- column_names[column_names > "a"   & column_names < "d"]
# function 
try_func <- function(data, col, cols) {
  data %>%
    mutate_at(vars(all_of(as.character(cols))), ~case_when(!!col==1 & . < 4.5 ~ "crit met", 
                                                           !!col==0 & . > 5 ~ "crit not met", 
                                                           TRUE ~ as.character(.))) 
}

try_func(data, col="a", cols=cols1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `!!col` gives the character string passed to `col`. Hence, your conditions evaluate to `FALSE`, i.e. you are checking e.g. `"a" == 0`. Instead you could use the `.data` pronoun when you pass a column name as a character string. Also note that `mutate_at` is superseded. Instead you could and should use `across`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

set.seed(1)

try_func <- function(data, col, cols) {
  data %>%
    mutate(across(all_of(cols), ~ case_when(
      .data[[col]] == 1 & . < 4.5 ~ "crit met",
      .data[[col]] == 0 & . > 5 ~ "crit not met",
      TRUE ~ as.character(.)
    )))
}

try_func(data, col = "a", cols = cols1)
#>    a                b                c         d
#> 1  0 4.17953161588198 2.95506639098477 4.8316138
#> 2  0     crit not met 2.98380973690105 4.5326135
#> 3  1 5.73832470512922         crit met 0.5877428
#> 4  1 5.57578135165349         crit met 3.5655498
#> 5  0 4.69461161284364 3.59390132121751 6.2538247
#> 6  1 6.51178116845085         crit met 9.0760387
#> 7  1 5.38984323641143         crit met 4.6916368
#> 8  1         crit met         crit met 6.1630148
#> 9  1         crit met         crit met 4.8385849
#> 10 0     crit not met 3.61982574789471 0.8688213
```

Comment: Any recommended text/source to learn about these different rules (specifically how to refer to variables from function input)?

Comment: See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html#data-masking and https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-inject.html.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `{{}}` to use unquoted variable names directly in dplyr.
I updated the code, replacing the superseded `mutate_at` and `vars` with current `mutate(across(....`

```
try_func <- function(data, col, cols) {
    data %>%
        mutate(across(all_of(as.character(cols)),
                      \(x) case_when({{col}}==1 & x < 4.5 ~ "crit met", 
                                     {{col}}==0 & x > 5 ~ "crit not met", 
                                     .default = as.character(x))))
}

try_func(data, col=a, cols=cols1)

   a                b                c         d
1  0 4.17953161588198 2.95506639098477 4.8316138
2  0     crit not met 2.98380973690105 4.5326135
3  1 5.73832470512922         crit met 0.5877428
4  1 5.57578135165349         crit met 3.5655498
5  0 4.69461161284364 3.59390132121751 6.2538247
6  1 6.51178116845085         crit met 9.0760387
7  1 5.38984323641143         crit met 4.6916368
8  1         crit met         crit met 6.1630148
9  1         crit met         crit met 4.8385849
10 0     crit not met 3.61982574789471 0.8688213
```

Obs: used set.seed(1), as did @stefan